# Zabbix Web Monitoring without interfaces

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I want to send HTTP request to a website where I can't deploy a Zabbix agent. I can only access the website via HTTP / HTTPS.

I created a host, but I **had to** setup a false interface (I wrote Zabbix Agent / the website DNS and port 10050). Consequently, the status is "Red" as Zabbix Server cannot connect to the agent.

How can I set up an agent without any interfaces, or more precisely, without triggering a "Red" status on the host ? In my situation, is there any way to get a "Green" status on the host ?

Zabbix version : 3.2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one interface is mandatory. Using `127.0.0.1` the status is Enabled, green. I'm using Zabbix 4 here.

[image: dummy interface]

[image: host status]

Answer (score 0):

Hosts in Zabbix must have at least one interface. That interface does not have to be used.

If you see the red "Z" and an error about contacting the agent, this means that you have created Zabbix agent items on that host (directly or via linking some template).

As those items do not work, it would be best to remove them.

See http://www.zabbixbook.com/2016/11/22/can-i-have-a-host-without-interfaces/ for more information.